# how to compare String and any type whether it is equal or not in swift?

Tags: swift, string, if-statement

For example,
`let a: String = "sat"
 let b: Any = "sat"`

`if a == b`

I tried that before.But it shows mismatching type string and any.
Please help me for this problem.I am new to swift.

Answer (score 2):

try below

```
if(a == "\(b)") // b automatically converted into 'Any' to 'String'
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is different is var a is String and var b is of Any(anyObject) so you can keep them equalivent. So workaround is change var b to String type before comparing  or at comparing

```
If a == (b as! String){    }
```

Or

```
If a == "/(b)"{    }
```

Comment: Causes app crash if "b" is nill

Answer (score 1):

If you face that error,First check what type of data it is.

```
let b: Any = "sat"
print(type(of: b))
```

It shows me String

[image]

Now we can check that by below

If we type cast b with string, the issue has gone.

```
if a == b as! String {
  ......        
}
```